# how to add in arrayList objects like { "color", "red", "style", "blue" }

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Hey I'm facing a problem related to ArrayList where i want to add Object like this { "color", "red", "style", "blue" }.

```
ArrayList<Object[][]> TAGS = new ArrayList<Object[][]>();

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    TAGS.add({ "color", "red", "style", "blue" });
}
```

if something is wrong please Forgive me since i am not a experience programmer. 
thanx in advance

Comment: Try this `{TAGS.add(new Object[][]{{ "color", "red", "style", "blue" }});}` But I'm not sure if it's what you meant

Comment: Why you need two dimensional array structure?

Comment: Please create a class with two variable (color and style)and then add the instance of the class (Object).

Comment: hey! can you do one more favor for me. how would i iterate my ArrayList !

Comment: yes! "Amit" you are right but this is something i want to know how this happens

Answer (score 0):

**I think all values you storing are String**

> try

```
    List<List<String>> TAGS = new ArrayList<>();

    TAGS.add(Arrays.asList("color", "red", "style", "blue"));
    TAGS.add(Arrays.asList( "tags", "one", "style", "blue"));
    TAGS.add(Arrays.asList( "weapon"));

    System.out.println(TAGS);
```

Comment: thanks man! it's works but what if i want list something like this [{ "color", "red", "style", "blue" },{ "tags", "one", "style", "blue" },{ "weapon" }];

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make an arrayList of string array.
You can achieve this by

```
 List<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<>();
 strings.add( new String[] {"Python","Java","Javascript"} );
 strings.add( new String[] {"one","two","three"} );
```

Comment: hey this is what is want as output 

[{"Python","Java","Javascript"},{"one","two","three"},{"Python","Language"},{"name","class"}]

is it possible?

Comment: you mean the output will be a list of string array as python?

Comment: You can print as `Python,Java,Javascript

one,two,three` by 
 for (String[] s : strings) {
    
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(s[i] + ",");
    }
   System.out.println();
  }

Then add square bracket and curly brace as you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a nested List, you can do something like below :

```
        List<List<String>> nestedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
        firstList.add("color");
        firstList.add("red");
        firstList.add("style");
        firstList.add("blue");
        nestedArrayList.add(firstList);
```